# How to make Springdoc to answer on /swagger-ui/ as Springfox was doing?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox, springdoc

I am trying to migrate from Springfox to Springdoc. I had Springfox answering on

```
http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/
```

How to make Springdoc to answer at the same place? I tries application.properties

```
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui/
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui/index.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/index.html
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/
```

but in all cases it was something different.

Comment: which version are you using? as https://springdoc.org/#properties you have done right with `springdoc.swagger-ui.path`. do you have any `context-path` in application? when you try http://localhost:8080/context-path/swagger-ui.html what are you getting with?

Comment: Also, you can't have `/` in the path that you specify in the `application.properties` file. Might as well try the following `springdoc.swagger-ui.path=swagger-ui`